# Why do I get the error message "! File ended while scanning use of \next." when using comment package?

Tags: texlive, tex-core

I have TexMaker in a desktop and I had it in a laptop where I produced several tex codes without problems. However, recently, I opened those codes in the desktop computer and I got the following error message "! File ended while scanning use of \next.". I surfed in Internet and I was able to find out that there was a "Tab" space after the \end{comment} code. After removing this "Tab" space, the error message does not show up and I can compile perfectly. Unfortunately, I had reinstalled the Unbuntu and TexMaker in the laptop, so I cannot check if the error appear in the laptop under the previous "conditions". However, I really believe that I was able to compile the tex files in the new desktop computer at least once. I noticed the problem after a crash in my Ubuntu when one of the tex files which had the problem was opened and I did a bruteforce restart by pressing the power button. Does anyone have any hint about this?

thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Characters after `\end{comment}` are a known thing to avoid -- the documentation for the comment package (https://ctan.math.illinois.edu/macros/latex/contrib/comment/writeup.pdf) says "The opening and closing commands should appear on a line of their own. No
starting spaces, nothing after it." I doubt it's related to having to restart your computer.

Answer (score 1):

You can not have characters after `\end{comment}` presumably because the package (being essentially a version of `verbatim` where normal processing of `\end` is disabled) looks for a line that literally matches the string `\end{comment}`.

However there was a change in the tex engines in texlive in (I think) 2020.

At the lowest level TeX normalises all input lines (before parsing for tokens), handling different platform line end conventions, and removing any trailing "blanks" at the end of each line.

For some years web2c based implementations had interpreted "blank" as including tabs and spaces, but it was confirmed that the original intention was just to remove spaces, so in current releases a tab character (ASCII 9) at the end of a line is not removed.  In most cases this is treated as a space and will be merged with the end of line, just generating a single space token, however in verbatim-like contexts as here, the character token can have an effect.

Comment: Very much thank you David, I hope this is what is going on.